# Flash: Possible to export song from Library? Or find it in a folder?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

Somehow in moving my flash project files to my external hard drive, I lost the two background music tracks. They still play in the swf, but they're nowhere to be found (when I click on properties, it has it sitting somewhere it clearly isn't).

Is there a way to export the sound to a new mp3? The sound file definitely exists, but I can't seem to find it or access it. I want to make a new version of this on iPad hence I need all the original sounds.

Comment: You might be able to do this with JSFL... check this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909053/is-it-possible-to-use-jsfl-to-export-sound-files-from-flash-library) and/or try searching with the terms "export mp3 from fla file with jsfl".

Comment: I have both the fla and the swf.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .FLA file you can just open it in WinRAR and go to LIBRARY folder, which contains all the stuff you had in your project library.

If you only have a .SWF file I recommend using [Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/), which you can try for free. From there you can export all the assets you want.

Comment: I'm on a mac, is there an alternative to WinRAR?

Comment: A little Google search won't hurt.. I'd go with The Unarchiver. You can get it from the app store. It's just a zip file, that's all.

Comment: It did unarchive the fla, but the files it outputted don't have a file extension, and when I add mp3 or wav they come out all screechy. Is there anything else I can do or am I on a fool's errand here?

Comment: There are swf decompilers for Mac also.

Comment: As @LarsBlåsjö said there are SWF decompilers for Mac too. There's nothing hard in what you want to do. Give your fla to your trustworthy friend with a Windows machine if you can't do anything else. I've used WinRAR countless times to do something like that, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: I've tried The Unarchiver for mac and the files that come out have no extensions and when I add mp3 or wav they are screechy nonsense. I tried to use WinRar on a PC and it just wouldn't open the fla, saying that it's not an archived file. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm.. strange.. Try decompiling your SWF then. That's the only way out I can think of.